# JavaScriptSerializer does not serialize a second level

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to use JavaScriptSerializer and I have got good results when I want to serialize a list of objects of a class like

```
public class employee
    {
        public string id;  //unique id of the employee
        public string displayName;
        public int displayFlag;

        public employee(string i, string dN, int dF)
        {
            id = i;
            displayName = dN;
            displayFlag = dF;
        }

    }
    public class data2
    {
        public List<employee> detail;

    }
```

When I do the following

```
  var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  string jsonData = json.Serialize(data2);
```

(and data2 is an object of class data2)

However when I try to do the same for something a little more complicated such as

```
  public class Ccanister
    {
        string identifier;
        public Ccanister(string c)
        {
            identifier = c;
        }
    }


    public class medicine
    {
        public string id; //unique id
        public string displayName;
        //and here an array of canisters
        public List<Ccanister> canister;

    }

    public class dataMedicine
    {
        public List<medicine> detail;  //Change this
    }
```

and I do this

```
  string jsonMedi = json.Serialize(dataM);
```

I got wrong results. 
dataM has correct results (I debugged it) but when jsonMedi gets its results, the canister list 'canister' is always empty. (It was not empty in dataM)

I wonder what I am doing wrong here

Comment: I thought you need a default constructor for the serializer to work

Comment: Can you post the actual output? Is the json for `canister` this: `[{}]` or this: `[]` ? I ask because you've made the `identifier` field of `Ccanister` private, which means it will not be serialized, but the *object* should be.

Comment: `[{}]` for canister

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem!